How can I pin the main menu in Android Studio Ladybug?
I'm running Android Studio Ladybug on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
The main menu looks like this by default (it's collapsed):

Is there a way to pin the main menu so that the main menu always displays?
The auto-collapse is terribly annoying.

Android Studio Version Info

Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-242.23339.11.2421.12550806, built on October 24, 2024
Runtime version: 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Toolkit: sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
Linux 6.8.0-48-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Concurrent GC, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 3880M
Cores: 16
Registry:
ide.experimental.ui=true
i18n.locale=
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME


Apart from pressing the hamburger item at the top-left or its associated shortcut (Alt+\ by default, or the shortcut of any of the main menu items like Alt+F) to instantly display the menu, you can permanently toggle it in the settings under
Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > Show main menu in a separate toolbar:

To reduce visual clutter it is deactivated by default though, it also consumes a (small) portion of the available screen space when activated.

Just tried it and the solution works.  Thanks very much.  I had search through those settings but had obviously overlooked that one.  So glad there is a way to customize it.  Thanks again.
